# How to display different images in mobile and desktop devices

Tags: html, css

Hi can anyone tell me how to display differnet banner images in desktop and mobile devices.Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="image\bannerimages\Career.png" class="img-responsive careerpage">
    <h2 class="careerbannertext">LIFE AT TEKNOTRAIT</h2>
    <h2 class="careerbannertext1">Are you fanatically driven and ready to take on some of the best challenges the industry has to offer? </h2>
    <h2 class="careerbannertext2">Come join us,be inspired to do the best work of your life!</h2>       
</div>
```

Right now in my desktop version it is displaying this image i need to change another image in mobile version.

Comment: Media Queries...Try search SO for that.

Comment: @Paulie_D but for hiding the image which is in desktop i need to use display none in media query then the image which i used then that will not be visible

Comment: Yep, then you need to have another image ready to show for mobile.

Comment: best example : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot remove my accepted answer, so please don't use it.
The best way is using tag picture with sources, like Ron.Basco post:

```
<picture>
   <source 
      media="(min-width: 650px)"
      srcset="images/img1.png">
   <source 
      media="(min-width: 465px)"
      srcset="images/img2.png">
   <img src="images/img-default.png" 
   alt="a cute kitten">
</picture>
```

My original accepted answer, which is not good, because images will be loaded on each device:

```css
.img-responsive.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .img-responsive {
    display: none;
  }
  .img-responsive.mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <img src="image\bannerimages\Career.png" class="img-responsive careerpage">
    <img src="image\bannerimages\Career-mobile.png" class="img-responsive careerpage mobile">
    <h2 class="careerbannertext">LIFE AT TEKNOTRAIT</h2>
    ...       
</div>
```

Comment: This will load both images on any device (and only displays one of them). Pretty bad for performance.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas Considering performance was the only reason that brought me here...

Comment: Unless both images are svg's and only 20kb in total, also if you need to still support <shudder> IE 11 for some older clients. 

But yes, the future is to use src sets.

Answer (score 68):

you can try this one:

```
<picture>
   <source 
      media="(min-width: 650px)"
      srcset="images/img1.png">
   <source 
      media="(min-width: 465px)"
      srcset="images/img2.png">
   <img src="images/img-default.png" 
   alt="a cute kitten">
</picture>
```

the image tag is still there so you can put a default image for the other browser that doesnt support the picture tag.

Comment: `srcset` is not compatible on internet explorer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: that's why it uses `<img src="images/img-default.png" ` for the fallback if the browser doesnt support it

Comment: This looks interesting, gonna try it with my new homepage. Bet it'd be awesome.

Answer (score 6):

You can use source element by adding a media attribute with the value (orientation: portrait) for mobile devices and (orientation: landscape) for desktop devices.

Example:

```
<picture>
   <source 
      media="(orientation: landscape)"
      srcset="testlandscape.png">
   <source 
      media="(orientation: portrait)"
      srcset="testportrait.png">
      
 <img src="testlandscape.png" width="100%" height="auto">
</picture>
```