# Display/Load Different Background Image Depending on Device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to use a large background image for desktop users and a different smaller background image for mobile users.

I found this answer

```css
.img-responsive.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .img-responsive {
    display: none;
  }
  .img-responsive.mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <img src="image\bannerimages\Career.png" class="img-responsive careerpage">
    <img src="image\bannerimages\Career-mobile.png" class="img-responsive careerpage mobile">
    <h2 class="careerbannertext">LIFE AT TEKNOTRAIT</h2>
    ...       
</div>
```

[how-to-display-different-images-in-mobile-and-desktop-devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891785/how-to-display-different-images-in-mobile-and-desktop-devices)

**Problem with this solution is it loads two images - I'd like to only load the image necessary. How can this be done?**

Comment: use background-image instead img tag

Comment: If you need different sizes for an img tag, use srcset. The browser will pick the best image for the device.

Comment: you can also achive it by using media-queries and background-image in css

Comment: @JonathanNicol srcset definitely a good answer for this and src as fallback for IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using pure Javascript**

javascript:

```
<script>
        var screenWidth = screen.width;
        var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
        var imgUrl;

        if(screenWidth < 480) {
            // for mobile devices
            imgUrl = document.createTextNode("url of img 1");
        } else {
            // otherwise
            imgUrl = document.createTextNode("url of img 2");
        }

        var row = document.getElementByClassName("row");
        row.insertBefore(imgElement, row.childNodes[0]);
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <h2 class="careerbannertext">LIFE AT TEKNOTRAIT</h2>
    ...       
</div>
```

I think html code is crystal clear so I just describe javascript code. first of all gets width of screen then checks whether it is a mobile device or others. then inserts url of proper image in created element and finally inserts it as the first element of `div.row` element.

Also you can do this easier using jQuery.

Comment: I noticed that code should also contain event checking if `x` changes in scenario "What if I will resize my browser window on deskop"

Comment: @hodiecode create a function, place the code in it. run the function inside an always true while loop.

Comment: the effect would be astoning xD by the `x` i meant `screenWidth`, sorry ;]

Comment: my answer is 
    `window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
       var screenWidth = screen.width;
       ...
       row.insertBefore(imgElement, row.childNodes[0]);

      })`
plus checking if img that already is in the row has different value

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <img id="img1" src="image\bannerimages\Career.png" class="img-responsive careerpage">
    <img id="img2" src="image\bannerimages\Career-mobile.png" class="img-responsive careerpage mobile">
    <h2 class="careerbannertext">LIFE AT TEKNOTRAIT</h2>
    ...       
</div> 


var w = window; 
var x = w.innerWidth;

if(x<568){
document.getElementsById('img2');
}
else{
document.getElementsById('img1');
}
```

Not sure without a full syntax, try this way Hope it works)